# Adding loop to array

Tags: arrays, loops, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm trying to add the results of a loop to an array.

Here is my code:

```
  <cfset mobNumbers = ArrayNew(1)>

<cfloop query = "staffLoop">
    <cfscript>

      mobileNo = staffLoop.mobileno;
      mobileNo = mobileNo.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
      ext = staffLoop.extension;
      ext = ext.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

      if (Left(mobileNo, 2) == "07" || Left(mobileNo, 3) == "447") {
        recipient = mobileNo;
      } else if (Left(ext, 2) == "07" || Left(ext, 3) == "447") {
        recipient = ext;
      } else {
        recipient = "";
      }

      if (Left(recipient, 2) == "07") {
        recipient = "447" & Right(recipient, Len(recipient) - 2);
      }

      if (Len(recipient) == 12) {

       [send text code]

      }
    </cfscript>
  </cfloop>
<cfset ArrayAppend(mobNumbers, "recipient")>
```

The goal is to get an array of all mobile numbers.

My code isn't working and I'm after some research, I'm not sure what to do. Any ideas?

If possible I'd like to use non-cfscript for my solution but if using cfscript is easier, that's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Adam points out, the ArrayAppend needs to be inside the loop. You'll also need to remove the quotes around the "recipient" in your call to ArrayAppend, otherwire you'll have an array of the String "recipient".

Comment: Thanks. On a related note, my code errors because of the `mobileNo = mobileNo.replaceAll` It does not like the replaceAll and I'm not sure why. Maybe I should start another question. When I comment out `mobileNo = mobileNo.replaceAll`, it does not error with the other replaceAll.

Comment: replaceAll is a java method of the String class, so it's not directly supported in ColdFusion but can be used. Look here for an example of Ben Nadel using it though: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1488-ColdFusion-Regular-Expressions-Do-Not-Support-Character-Class-Intersection-Or-Subtraction.htm

Comment: @barnyr Thanks. Adding JavaCast didn't seem to help but will try and solve it.

Comment: @Alias - Unless there is a specific reason for using `String.replaceAll`, just use CF's `reReplace` function http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e98.html

Answer (score 1):

Your `arrayAppend()` needs to be *inside* the loop, otherwise you're just appending the last result after the loop has finished.